# I want to make sure that every row in a Microsoft SQL table is unique

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to make sure that every row in a Microsoft SQL table is unique. Of course we could had a unique index on every row but it was proposed by someone to add a computed column that hashes every column and then add a unique index on that column. Can someone point me towards anything that says whether that way has any benefits?

Comment: Use an unique index sounds like the best solution, what would be the reason for the overhead with a calculated column?

Comment: If you are using MS EF or some other ORM I believe that should automatically take care of this by auto incrementing the Id field. Also there are many advantages, as all the Ids in columns are unique and it is easy to have a foreign key relationship

Comment: The advantage of the unique constraint over all of the columns is the *optimizer can make use of this information in planning its queries*. No such possibility with this hashed column *unless* that column is being specifically queried for.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The thought is that it would have less overhead as the index would just be on one column instead of 25.

Comment: Yes but you would need to update this column every time a row is updated

Comment: @JoakimDanielson That is a good point but fortunately in this situation the tables would be write only - we would insert a row and then that row's data would never change.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to guarantee that every row is unique, then use a unique index on all the columns.

You *can* use a hashing function, but you run the risk of collisions -- two different rows that hash to the same value.

Using hashes for matching full rows is a good idea.  It can improve performance for matching full rows, for instance.  However, there is a second step when two hash values match; that second step is a full comparison of the entire row values.